# error 500 al insetar

Tags: php, base-de-datos

```
<?php

    define('DBHOST', '')
         define('DBUSER', '')
    define('DBPASS', '')
         define('DBNAME', '')

        $conn =mysqli_connect('DBHOST','DBUSER','DBPASS','DBNAME')
     echo "conexion correcta"
        if (!$conn){
     die("conection failed". mysqli_connect_error());
        echo "la conexion ha fallado";
    }



      $titulo = isset($_POST['titulo']) ? $_POST['titulo']:null;
                 echo"l titulo  es:".$titulo.'<br>';
      $autor = isset($_POST['autor']) ? $_POST['autor']:null;
      $editorial= isset($_POST['editorial']) ? $_POST['editorial']:null;
     $prestado = isset($_POST['prestado']) ? $_POST['prestado']:null;
      $fechaprestamo = isset($_POST['fechaprestamo']) ? $_POST['fechaprestamo']:null;

       $fechadevolucion = isset($_POST['fechadevolucion']) ? $_POST['fechadevolucion']:null;
       $isbn = isset($_POST['isbn']) ? $_POST['isbn']:null;
       $fechaAlta= isset($_POST['fechaAlta']) ? $_POST['fechaAlta']:
            null;
        $conn= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                if($conn->connect_error){
                      die("connection failed".$con->connect_error);
                 echo "la conexion no funciona"."<br>";
             }else{
       echo "conectado correctamente"."<br>";
        }

           $sql="INSERT INTO libros(titulo, autor, editorial,prestado, fechaprestamo, fechadevolucion, 
        isbn, fechaAlta)VALUES('$titulo', '$autor', '$editorial', '$prestado', '$fechaprestamo', 
             '$fechadevolucion', '$isbn', '$fechaAlta')";
                     echo mysqli_error($conn);
                    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
                       echo "datos introducidos";
                      }else{
                   echo "error".$sql."<br>".mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
              ?>
```

Comment: Este mensaje se produce por un error de sintáxis en PHP como falta de punto y coma para finalizar una línea, un paréntesis o llave mal puesto, etc. Necesitas revisar el registro de errores para saber exactamente cuál es el problema.

Comment: Revisando rápidamente, tus primeras líneas no terminan con `;`